# Dynamically add EditText, Spinner, Radiobutton in Android

Tags: android

Need to add EditText, Spinner And Radiobutton based on the array length.

```
gQuestionEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.QuestionEditExt);
        gQuestionSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerQuestion);
        gQuestionRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.QuestionRadiobutton);

        for (int i = 0; i < SubSlotId.size(); i++) {

        }
```

Based on the array size i need to add the EditText,Spinner and Radio Button, please suggest me  to add, and how to differentiate the ID's and get the values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to add dynamic views like EditText, TextView, Spinner, RadioButton,.. to your layout based on size of your array. This is just a sample code, not tested.

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setId(editText.generateViewId());
ll.addView(editText);

Spinner dynamicSpinner = new Spinner(this);
options = new ArrayList<String>();
options.add("January");
options.add("February");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, options);
dynamicSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
ll.addView(dynamicSpinner);

RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
rdbtn.setId(rdbtn.generateViewId());
rdbtn.setText("Radio " + rdbtn.getId());
ll.addView(rdbtn);
```

`editText.generateViewId()` this will generate unique Id for your view, this can be used to get the details of the view at later point of time...

Comment: Its not working, it shows some error like constructor is undefined, any other option to add view dynamically

Comment: its not an logcat error, i need to add the view in my method not an activity,do you have any idea to add the view in my particular method,

Comment: You can add it in your method, but instead of 'this' use 'YourActivity.this' or applicationContext while creating views. Eg. EditText editText = new EditText(YourActivityName.this);

Comment: You can get the applicationContext by using the method getApplicationContext()    Eg. EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());

Comment: thanks, its working, but i need to add those views in mid of my activity, it cause design alignment issue as well my scroll view is not working after add a edittext dynamically, any idea about this, please suggest

Comment: you need to set property of parent to enable scroll bar if it exceeds specific height or add a scroll view to parent
or You can pre-define styles and add them to your newly created Views

Comment: successfully scroll is working but, the view which i have added is not showing in the particular activity.

Comment: Have you added newly created view to your activity?

Comment: Yes Successfully added but the problem is, whenever i load the views second time need to clear the existing view how can it is possible tried with many code bt no luck...

Comment: You can remove/clear views by using                         ll.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ll.removeView(editText); ll.removeView(dynamicSpinner); ll.removeView(rdbtn);
    }
}); or If you want to remove all the views try l1.removeAllViews();

Comment: LinearLayout li = new LinearLayout(this); li.removeAllViews(); i have used this to clear my view, thanks for your answer.